# Add multiple pictures in one Content Slider all at once

Tags: typo3

I have to add about 100 pictures in a content slider.

Each time, I have to add each picture seperatly... this is painfully slow.

Is there a way to add them all at once to the content slider?

Comment: 'content slider'? you might give more information about your system. which TYPO3 version, which extension, ...

Answer (score 0):

In most places TYPO3 enables you to add multiple records from the record selector popup. Just use the `+` buttons/ links instead of clicking on the record name.